# General theorems for proving the convergence of improper integrals?

Tags: calculus

I am wondering if there are any general theorems for proving the convergence of improper integrals. For example, does an analogous result to the ratio test exist for integrals? Wikipedia gives around 10 different convergence criteria for series but I could not find a comprehensive list for integrals

Comment: The main one is the comparison test (which is indeed analogous to the comparison test for series), together with elementary evaluations like for $\int \frac1{x^p}\,dx$. I believe there is an analogue of the root test for integrals, although comparison tests usually cover such cases anyway.

Comment: And the ratio test for series basically boils down to the comparison test anyway, with a geometric series. So the comparison test for improper integrals would cover anything analogous to that. But note that something _exactly_ like the ratio test wouldn't really make sense for integrals, since it refers to the consecutive terms of the series, but a function being integrated has no such thing as "consecutive" values. (What's the "next" real number after √2, for example?)